# Slash in rel attribute of LINK element

Tags: html, css

I've been looking into [less](http://lesscss.org) and I notice that you use

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" ...>
```

to use the LESS file.  However, I've been looking through the HTML standards and I don't see anywhere where this format for a "rel" attribute is allowed, or if so what the definition is.  If I were to use some other identifier,

```
<link rel="stylesheet/something" ...>
```

what effect would this have?  Is it defined how browsers are supposed to interpret it?  Or is this just something that less.js would look for and remove before the browser ever processes it?  Thanks, I'd like to know how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this just something that less.js would look for and remove before the browser ever processes it?

This seems to be true. This pattern is used by `less.js` (line 5372 for [v. 1.4.1](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/master/dist/less-1.4.1.js)) to collect the LESS files to be processed and converted into real CSS.

Comment: Yep, and it looks like createCSS() is what removes the `<link>` element and replaces it ... thanks!